# Any method to determine the gravitational constant $G$ from observations in cosmological scale?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, experimental-physics, astrophysics, physical-constants

By the observations in cosmological scale, I mean observations by astrophysicists like motions of quasars in far distance from us, relative motions of our galaxy to others, etc.

I know the famous experiment by Cavendish to determine the numerical value of $G$, but how could we convince the *universal* law of gravitation (or, that in modern form, the Einstein equation) really universal (in cosmological scale)?